# BASH cannot find hidden file that exists using ~/ in path

Tags: bash, hidden-files

I have a BASH script that is looking for a hidden file in my home directory.  When I specify the absolute path `/home/user/.foo` in trying to find the file then the script will find it but if I use `~/.foo` then the script cannot find the file. Can someone explain why this is happening and what other way I can find the file.  I want to be able to find the file on different user's home directory and not just my own.

Sorry for not providing the snippet of code but here it is

`file="~/.foo"`

`[ -f $file ] && echo "foo exists!"`

this however works

`file="home/user/.foo"`

`[ -f $file ] && echo "foo exists!"`

Comment: Hove you put `~` in quotes?

Comment: Strange. For me ~/.filename is working to reference a file.

Comment: @RouvenB. That's because you are doing *something entirely different*.

Comment: Yup, makes sense after the edit ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the shell only performs **tilde expansion** when the tilde is the first unquoted character in a **word**. In

```
file="~/.foo"
```

the tilde is quoted with double quotes, so is left unexpanded. The best practice is to always use `$HOME` when the tilde is supposed to expand to your home directory (and not some other user's as in `~user`.

The straight dope from [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01):

> 2.6.1 Tilde Expansion
>
> A "tilde-prefix" consists of an unquoted <tilde> character at the
>   beginning of a word, followed by all of the characters preceding the
>   first unquoted <slash> in the word, or all the characters in the word
>   if there is no <slash>. In an assignment (see XBD Variable
>   Assignment), multiple tilde-prefixes can be used: at the beginning of
>   the word (that is, following the <equals-sign> of the assignment),
>   following any unquoted <colon>, or both. A tilde-prefix in an
>   assignment is terminated by the first unquoted <colon> or <slash>. If
>   none of the characters in the tilde-prefix are quoted, the characters
>   in the tilde-prefix following the <tilde> are treated as a possible
>   login name from the user database. A portable login name cannot
>   contain characters outside the set given in the description of the
>   `LOGNAME` environment variable in XBD Other Environment Variables. If
>   the login name is null (that is, the tilde-prefix contains only the
>   tilde), the tilde-prefix is replaced by the value of the variable
>   `HOME`. If `HOME` is unset, the results are unspecified. Otherwise, the
>   tilde-prefix shall be replaced by a pathname of the initial working
>   directory associated with the login name obtained using the `getpwnam()`
>   function as defined in the System Interfaces volume of POSIX.1-2008.
>   If the system does not recognize the login name, the results are
>   undefined.
>
> The pathname resulting from tilde expansion shall be treated as if
>   quoted to prevent it being altered by field splitting and pathname
>   expansion.

Answer (score 3):

Always provide the code which does not work. From your description it cannot be reproduced:

```
$ ls ~/.foo
/home/user/.foo
```

As suggested by anishsane there may be quotes.

```
$ ls "~/.foo"
ls: cannot access ~/.foo: No such file or directory
```

But how to handle white space? Put the ~ outside the quotes:

```
$ ls ~/".f o o"
/home/user/.f o o
```

But also but the / outside the quotes, else ~ is not expanded

```
$ ls ~"/.f o o"
ls: cannot access ~/.f o o: No such file or directory
```